# How to Format a page for A4 size?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am new in PHP. I have a file code which contain multiple inline text editor. Data fetched from db in all editor. I want to format my page. The output of my page is below.

Here i face problem while printing. When i press `Ctrl+P` the formatting of my page will be changed. Text go out from the page.

Is there any solution for me?

My code is

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pacra1");

         $id2 = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 where id='$id2'";

            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $row= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC));

$editor1 =trim($row['editor1']);
$editor2 =trim($row['editor2']);
$editor3 =trim($row['editor3']);
$editor4 =trim($row['editor4']);
$editor5 =trim($row['editor5']);
$editor6 =trim($row['editor6']);
$editor7 =trim($row['editor7']);
$editor8 =trim($row['editor8']);
$editor9 =trim($row['editor9']);
$editor10 =trim($row['editor10']);
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcolorpicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxeditor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#editor1').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor2').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor3').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor4').jqxEditor({ 
            });

             $('#editor5').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor6').jqxEditor({ 
            });
            $('#editor7').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor8').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor9').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor10').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor11').jqxEditor({
            });

        });
    </script>

    <div style=" margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 60%">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">

    <div style=" margin:auto; width:60px; height:auto; align: middle">
    <img src="image/pacra_logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-variant: small-caps; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold">
    The Pakistan Credit Rating Agency Limited 
    <hr>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 30%;" contenteditable="true" id="editor1"><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor1))?(nl2br($editor1)):'';?></div>

           <div style=" margin-top:30px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:1" contenteditable="true" id="editor2"><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor2))?(nl2br($editor2)):'';?></div>

            <div style=" margin-top:30px; margin-left:220px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:right; line-height:1; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" id="editor3"><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor3))?(nl2br($editor3)):'';?></div>

             <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          <div style="margin-top:40px; margin-right:auto; width:auto; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:center; font-variant:small-caps; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold" contenteditable="true" id="editor4"><p> <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor4))?(nl2br($editor4)):'';?> </p></div>

         <div style=" margin-top:20px; width:20%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true" id="editor5"> 
         <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor5))?(nl2br($editor5)):'';?>
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px; text-align:justify; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" id="editor6">

            <?php echo !empty(trim(nl2br($editor6)))? (trim(nl2br($editor6))):'';?>
        </div>

    <div style="margin-top:30px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true" id="editor7">
    <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor7))?(nl2br($editor7)):'';?>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:100px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px; font-variant:small-caps" contenteditable="true" id="editor8">
    <strong><p><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor8))?(nl2br($editor8)):'';?></p></strong>
    </div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true" id="editor9">
  <p><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor9))?(nl2br($editor9)):'';?></p>
    </div>    

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:40px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true" id="editor10">
  <p><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor10))?(nl2br($editor10)):'';?></p>
    </div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:70px; width:800px; float:left; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18px;">
    <hr>
 <strong></strong>  
 </br>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you are using HTML. HTML is made for browser use and not to be printed. Use PDF as output for your data if you want something printable, or keep your data width really conservative small so it will always fit. YOu will run into page length issues too....

Comment: suggest pdf, HTML is not the language for print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I do it.
Look my updates code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pacra1");

         $id2 = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 where id='$id2'";

            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $row= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC));

$editor1 =trim($row['editor1']);
$editor2 =trim($row['editor2']);
$editor3 =trim($row['editor3']);
$editor4 =trim($row['editor4']);
$editor5 =trim($row['editor5']);
$editor6 =trim($row['editor6']);
$editor7 =trim($row['editor7']);
$editor8 =trim($row['editor8']);
$editor9 =trim($row['editor9']);
$editor10 =trim($row['editor10']);
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
 body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        font: 12pt "Tahoma";
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .page {
        width: 210mm;
        min-height: 297mm;
        padding: 20mm;
        margin: 10mm auto;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .subpage {
        padding: 1cm;
        border: 5px solid;
        height: 257mm;
        outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
    }

    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;        
        }
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }


</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcolorpicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxeditor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#editor1').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor2').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor3').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor4').jqxEditor({ 
            });

             $('#editor5').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor6').jqxEditor({ 
            });
            $('#editor7').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor8').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor9').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor10').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor11').jqxEditor({
            });

        });
    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.print();
   </script>

    <div class="page">
    <div style=" font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">

    <div style=" margin:auto; width:60px; height:auto; align: middle">
    <img src="image/pacra_logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-variant: small-caps; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold">
    The Pakistan Credit Rating Agency Limited 
    <hr>
    </div>

    <div style="width: auto; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif" contenteditable="true" id="editor1"><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor1))?(nl2br($editor1)):'';?></div>

           <div style=" margin-top:30px; width:auto; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:1" contenteditable="true" id="editor2"><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor2))?(nl2br($editor2)):'';?></div>

            <div style=" margin-top:30px; margin-left:350px; width:auto; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:right; line-height:1; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" id="editor3"><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor3))?(nl2br($editor3)):'';?></div>

             <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          <div style="margin-top:40px; margin-right:auto; width:auto; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:center; font-variant:small-caps; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold" contenteditable="true" id="editor4"><p> <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor4))?(nl2br($editor4)):'';?> </p></div>

         <div style=" margin-top:20px; width:auto; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true" id="editor5"> 
         <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor5))?(nl2br($editor5)):'';?>
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: auto; text-align:justify; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" id="editor6">

            <?php echo !empty(trim(nl2br($editor6)))? (trim(nl2br($editor6))):'';?>
        </div>

    <div style="margin-top:30px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true" id="editor7">
    <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor7))?(nl2br($editor7)):'';?>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:100px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px; font-variant:small-caps" contenteditable="true" id="editor8">
    <strong><p><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor8))?(nl2br($editor8)):'';?></p></strong>
    </div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true" id="editor9">
  <p><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor9))?(nl2br($editor9)):'';?></p>
    </div>    

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:40px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true" id="editor10">
  <p><?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor10))?(nl2br($editor10)):'';?></p>
    </div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:70px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18px;">
    <hr>
 <strong>Awami Complex FB-1, Usman Block, New Garden Town, Lahore-54600, Pakistan</strong>  
 </br>PABX: 92(42)35869507 Fax: 92(42)35830425 Email: pacra@pacra.com 
 </br>www.pacra.com
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify style for print in a seperate css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css"/ media="print">
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set
`@media print { }`

in css like this:

```
 @media print {
     body {
         width: 210mm;
         min-height: 297mm;
         background: white;
     } 
 }
```